# Confusion about syntax for notarizing an app using xcrun altool

Tags: applications, xcode, notarization

I'm trying to obtain notarization for an app I developed outside Xcode but instead wrote using python and pyinstaller and that I wish to share outside the app store. I have a Developer's license, but am completely new to the notarization process and have been searching all over for assistance.

I first stored my Apple credentials using

```
xcrun altool --store-password-in-keychain-item "AC_PASSWORD" -u "my_email@gmail.com" -p 
"my_apple-password"
```

At the developer's website I created a certificate, developerID_application.cer, which I uploaded to my keychain and see listed as Developer ID Application: MyName (TeamID)

I then signed the app using

```
codesign -s "MyName (TeamID)" -v --deep --timestamp --entitlements entitlements.plist 
-o runtime "dist/My Application.app"
```

entitlements.plist is included here since the binaries were built using pyinstaller. (I'm following advice given at https://haim.dev/posts/2020-08-08-python-macos-app/.)

From what I can tell, the signing works. Now I attempt to notarize via

```
xcrun altool —notarize-app -f 
/Users/my_name/Desktop/my_application.zip --primary-bundle-id 
TeamID -u my_email@gmail.com —password "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD"
```

The resulting error message states "No command argument was specified"

What is the fundamental issue I'm overlooking?

Comment: How are you waiting and polling to see that the notarization is finished? Here is an excellent article that describes this in detail - https://twocanoes.com/adding-notarization-to-xcode-builds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `-`, it should be `--notarize-app`. For example:

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app -f <file> --primary-bundle-id <bundleID> -u <appleID> —p <password or keychain reference>
```

Comment: Thank you. When I make the correction, I assume the password is for my developer's account. I'm then prompted for my_email@gmail.com password. Am I correct that I use here my actual gmail password itself? I tried various things here but still received "Failed to get authorization" errors.

Comment: @fishbacp: You need to pass your Apple ID email & password (like you would use to log into https://developer.apple.com , for example). So it's not your Gmail password. I wrote a detailed answer on [how to store the password in the keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396125/400056) instead.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm still somewhat confused. I went to your second link and added a generic password using Keychain Access App. I named the password AC_PASSWORD. For account name I used my developer's id and for password I used my developer's password.

Comment: @fishbacp: So what's the question, then? You only described what you did, not what kind of problem you ran into.

Comment: Sorry-still somewhat confused. I went to your second link and added a generic password using Keychain Access App. I named the password AC_PASSWORD. For account name I used my dev id and for password I used my dev password. I entered 

xcrun altool  --notarize-app -f "/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/my_application.zip" --primary-bundle-id TeamID -u fishback.paul@gmail.com --p "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD"  

I'm prompted for a PWD, which I assume is for my developer. Still get "Unable to upload your app for notarization. Failed to get authorization for username 'fishback.paul@gmail.com' and password."

Comment: The argument for the password is `-p` or `--password`. The number of `-` is important in each case. I completely forgot about it: if your Apple ID has 2FA enabled (which is very likely nowadays), Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow/notarizing_apps_when_developing_with_xcode_12_and_earlier) says you need to [set up an App Specific Password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397) and use this instead of your normal Apple ID password.

Comment: You were right! An app-specific password was needed. Thanks again.